# Designing a logarithmic/phyllotactic-like pattern in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustration

After watching today's Apple Keynote, I witnessed a modal used in one of the HomePod slides. It shows a mesh design for the fabric that encloses the device.

How might I reproduce this in Illustrator? At least the shape. Not the entire gradient color and shading.

I'm assuming I'll need to create a spiral graph, however I am having a hard time doing that in Illustrator.

[image: Example pattern]

Comment: Somewhat related to **[Illustrator: how to create a spirograph?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/85557/18306)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here goes for the shape...I can further my answer tomorrow if you require more help for shading.

1. Create an elliptical shape in Illustrator.
2. Rotate it by 137.5 degrees and copy it. (Also known as the Golden
   Angle...this is key!)
3. Hit ctrl+d or cmd+d to duplicate until your shapes start to seem
   thicker (that means you went too far so you can undo until you have
   a nice, uniform texture).
4. Cover the center with a circle. Go on with recreating the
   shading!

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Amazing. This really helped. Thank you for your post and the the visuals. I was doing angles of about 105 degrees. A larger angle at a fraction of a degree really helps. You rock!

Comment: The Golden Angle is approximately 137.5077640500378546463487 so it's not perfectly equal everywhere. Glad it could be helpful!