# Creating Archimedean Pentagon Spiral in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-scripting

Does anyone know how to create an Archimedean Pentagon Spiral in Illustrator without having to hand-draw or using the Blend tool?  A script where the math can be controlled would be ideal.[image]

Comment: Your image does not look pentagonal to me.

Comment: A grid made of triangles strikes me as a good start, you could just merge them accordingly with the shape composer but this will not allow to control the math. When I google Archimedean Pentagon Spiral the images I get are not as close to the example your provide. This may be of interest... https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/92700/how-do-i-design-this-logarithmic-phyllotactic-like-pattern-in-illustrator/92705#92705

Comment: The attached image is an example of an Polygonal Archimedean Spiral, not necessarily pentagonal.

Comment: Stop! My eyes are hurting! :)

Comment: Well, the interpolation of jooGraphFunction.could be modified so that it does not try to fit the tangents. IN fact it is present in teh s script itself replace text "plotSmooth"  on line 198 with "plotLinear"

Answer (score 3):

I have updated [jooGraphFunction](https://bitbucket.org/joojaa/jooillustratorscripts/src) so that you can now choose to plot with linear segments via the new **method** drop down.

[image]

**Image 1**: Example of linear method.

Hopefully somebody else also finds this useful. I was planning to also add a option for a 2D plot (like in [this post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/78676/isometric-bulging-grid/78680#78680)), unfortunately changes for this are on hold. Hopefully somebody finds this small change done so far useful in their day to day work.

[image]

**Image 2**: Just for fun.

Comment: Sorry for the moire ;P

Answer (score 2):

Here's a script to make a round [Archimedian spiral](http://shspage.com/aijs/en/#TOP) which I found by googling. Perhaps you could modify it. Sadly, it's beyond my ablities to do so.

Alternatively, if '*joining the dots*' is OK, create a grid with the Polar grid tool, ungroup it, and delete the horizontal, vertical and diagonal lines.

Transform a line with 72 degree rotations around the centre of the polar grid, and turn everything into guides.

Enable Smart Guides and snapping, and draw your spiral with the Pen tool, by joining up the intersections.

[image]